# How to add Meta charset to wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding, meta

Geeks, how do i add meta charset to my website? I checked my website's analysis and realised that that Meta charset is missing...I just want my site to have better design standard

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two ways: 
1. hardcode it in template directly (usually in file header.php) i.e.:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>
```

2. use action hook wp_head to insert a charset line from within plugin/or theme actions.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following line just under the opening `<head>` tag...

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
```

Hope that helps

Regards

Dan